# Requires Android: Varies with device (Multi APK)

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console

I'm working on an app which is in Beta (no released version in production yet).

I've uploaded a new APK yesterday. When doing that I got a warning as I changed the minSdkVersion from 16 to 19. I made this change on purpose so it was expected.

On the Google Play Console, it now shows that a new APK has been added and the old one has be deactivated, which is what I want.

[image]

However, the Play Store now display 'Varies with device' under the 'Requires Android' section of the app information.

So it seems the Store has kept the old version for the people having Android between API 16 and 19, like if I wanted [Multiple APK](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks).

How to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

I've released a new Alpha version to get rid of the old one which was still there and 'shadowed' by the Beta (this Alpha supported Android from API 16), and then promoted it to Beta. So now I have no Alpha, still no app in production, and only one Beta APK with minSdkVersion set to 19.

This Beta is now displayed on the Store page, however both `'Requires Android'` and `Current version` still display `'Varies with device'`.

Comment: I believe this will go away once you go to production. Some of your users (the ones not in beta) still receive the 16+ version of your app.

Comment: There is no release version at all yet. But thanks to your comment, I think I found why. There is an Alpha version still active. The app used to be in alpha but now I publish it in Beta straight away. How can I disable / unpublish the Alpha version?

Comment: One of the options is probably to publish a new version in alpha to override the current one and then push it in beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting Google support, here is their answer:

> I looked into your matter further and the reason why you can see the
>   'Varies with device' under 'Requires Android' is because the app is
>   unreleased.
>
> Please note that if the app is published then the section for
>   'Requires Android' will be updated with the relevant information.

So I'll see if the values are correctly updated when I'll release the app.

Comment: Have you released your app? What happened with the 'Varies with device'. I've uploaded my first APK with a lower version, it's no longer active in any releases. But I still get the 'Varies with device' under both Latest Version and Requires Android

Comment: @groveale The app has been released. There is no Alpha nor Beta versions available anymore, and the information is now correctly displayed on the Play Store page. So the above answer from Google support is correct